# Unexpected result from nested for loop - Python

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, nested-loops

I'm trying to run a nested for loop with a conditional statement. When running it, I expect it to print the statement that I defined if my conditional statement. But it doesn't print anything. (and it doesn't run indefinitely). Pokemons_gyms is a list of strings. Players is a dictionary. I tried adding `else: continue` but it doesn't work. I'm stuck cause I don't get any error running the code...

```
pokemon_gyms = ['reddit.com', 'amazon.com', 'twitter.com', 
            'linkedin.com', 'ebay.com','netflix.com',
            'udacity.com','stackoverflow.com','github.com',
            'quora.com']

players= {
    1: {
        'gyms_visited': ['amazon.com', 'ebay.com']
        }
    2:{
        'gyms_visited' : ['stackoverflow.com','github.com']
      }
}

for gym in pokemon_gyms:     
    for players_id in players:
        if gym == players[players_id]['gyms_visited']:
            print(str(players[players_id]['player_name']) +" has visited "+ str(gym))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`players[players_id]['gyms_visited']` returns a list so `gym == players[players_id]['gyms_visited']` always evaluates to `False`.

You should check for membership using `in`:

```
if gym in players[players_id]['gyms_visited']:
    ...
```

Comment: "is" and "evaluates to", respectively; not "returns". There are no returns here.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition -- maybe.  At a low enough level, we're talking about what `__getitem__` is going to return, so there _is_ a return value here, it's just not so explicit.

Comment: @mgilson: heh nice maneuvering. Still, it wouldn't be correct to say "X returns Y" even though "X" was produced through a return from some function

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that `gym` is going to be a `str` while `players[players_id]['gyms_visited']` is a *list* of strings.  Because of this, they will never be equal.

Perhaps you want to check

```
if gym in players[players_id]['gyms_visited']:
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the line `if gym == players[players_id]['gyms_visited']:`. `==` checks for equality so this will look if `gym` is equal to the list in `players[players_id]['gyms_visited']` in the dictionary.

If you want to check if the any of the items in the list is equal to the string you can use the `in` keyword

```
for gym in pokemon_gyms:
    for players_id in players:
        if gym in players[player_id]['gyms_visited']:
            # Do things here
```

Notice that for large lists this can be rather slow so you might want to consider using a [set](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) instead if you are going to have players with lots of visited pokemon_gyms.

Answer (score 0):

YUP! 
All set, it was '==' that was resulting to all results being False because of type(gym) is different from type(players[players_id]['gyms_visited']).

I replaced '==' by 'in' and it worked perfectly.

Thank you guys!

Comment: = is an assignment operator
== is an equality operator